# I have a problem with git in the environment variables

Tags: git, flutter, cmd

I was trying to solve a problem with the java using **cmd** but I accidentally deleted the path of the system variables...
I re-created it but now the git throws me this problem in the cmd:

> 'where' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
>   Error: Unable to find git in your PATH.

Comment: Do you know where you have installed `git` ? Here is a [tutorial](https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm) on how to update your `PATH` environment variable on windows

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow Lola! Something is trying to give to CMD the command `where`, can you please put in the question more information, like the command that you are triggering and the status of the environmental variables you think are important in this case.

Comment: i have fixed the problem actually :) .. thanks for ur consideration tho